# Raja/Hatha yogi or yoginis mukthi should be through brahmarandhra?

Tags: yoga, moksha

Is it mentioned anywhere in the scripture that Yogis and Yoginis who follow Hath/Raja yoga mukthi should be through brahmarandhra/sahasrara?
If there is no sign should we conclude that they will be reborn?

What are the obvious signs of mukthi?

Comment: Question is - is it only for Raja yogis or general criteria for Moksha? I think moksha means Atma should exit the body via crown of head!

Comment: May be Raja yogis.. because they have only one way that is through practice of ashanas no need for God.. (According to pathanjali) I believe, its only practice that should lead to brahmarada, Bakthi yoga or other types wont stick to only one type but for yoga practitioners its only one way out.. exit through brahmaraadra @AkshayS

Comment: then how humans of Bhakti yoga quit the body?

Comment: Bhakthi Yoga believes different only God Grace deliver the moksha.. there is no mandate that it should through brahmaraadra.. For Moksha Yogi mandatory is prathyaksha of Lord Naryana, Veda sravana/(Understand BG, SrimadBhagavatha and constantly on trace through mediatation of lords feet). but to get prathyaksha you should have know your Atma(Atma shakshathkara is required).. beside various other criteria like have Guru upadesha various others, but there is no straight way to moksha. its very difficult. @AkshayS

Comment: Related or Duplicate of this one: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28811/how-a-devotee-of-god-leaves-his-body-for-moksha @PrasannaR

Comment: @PrasannaR even Vellukudi of Vaishnava says one should leave the body via crown of head for Moksha in a video but he didnt proceed further on how a devotee leaves the body or whether narayana himself picks up the Atma. From my limited knowledge on Nayanars of Shiva devotees never died but they merged to Shiva linga in various temples. So I dont know other side of this!

Comment: Then Vellukudi is negating all those Alzhwars, YadvaPraksha, Ramanuja, Vedanta desikan as not attained moksha because they have not left through brahmaraadra @akshayS

Comment: @PrasannaR Ok but this will trigger heated debates, so am quitting this discussion!

Comment: @Rickross may be its duplicate but im askin from Raja yogi prespective where do they believe only one way.  or many ways..

Comment: I think it is the same for them too @PrasannaR